# How to plot step response of a system with more zeros than poles(Without changing original transfer function)

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing

I am trying to plot step response of an electronic circuit(differentiator) using MATLAB but I get an error:

```
Error using DynamicSystem/step (line 95)
Cannot simulate the time response of models with more
zeros than poles.
```

My code is below:

```
R=47*10^3%resistance value
C=1*10^-6% capacitor value
den=[-1]%denominator of transfer function
num=[R*C 0]%numerator of transfer function
sys=tf(num,den)%transfer function expression of model/system
step(sys)%step response
```

How can I plot my graph of step response without changing my original transfer function? Because if I change the original transfer function, it will become a new system. However, I want to analyze original system.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding poles with very fast dynamic (going to `-inf` for continuous system, close to `0` for discrete). This will make the system to meet the criteria and will have minimal impact on the system dynamic. But as for the step response you will probably have some spikes and maybe some `nan` will pollute your results.

What is a system with more zeros than poles? You must have some derivatives in the response. What is the step response? Is the response of the system to a step input, and the step infput is not differentiable at `t = 0`. So, I would try to compute the response to another (differentiable) input.

Comment: "I would try adding poles with very fast dynamic" but that addition of poles will change the transfer function and the overall system. But in my question i asked, how cancan I plot my graph of step resposne without changing my original transfer function?

Comment: If you want the numeric impulse response you will have to smooth it, because you can't evaluate numerically the derivative of the step function.